# Curl drops last 5 bytes but wget works fine

Tags: java, curl, kotlin, wget

I have a Kotlin program which I am using to serve a file to a remote host. I am trying to get the file at the remote host with curl. This program works fine for me for files that are pure text, but for .jar files it always loses exactly 5 bytes. wget, on the other hand, works without any issue and does not lose the 5 bytes.

Here, in case it is useful, is the Kotlin code

```
            val client = serverSocket.accept()
            val file = File(pathToFile)
            val bytes = ByteArray(16 * 1024)
            val instream = FileInputStream(file)
            val out = BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream())

            var count: Int
            var sm = 0
            count = instream.read(bytes)

            while (count > 0) {
                sm += count
                out.write(bytes, 0, count)
                count = instream.read(bytes)
            }
            print("total bytes : $sm")
            out.flush()
            out.close()
```

Here are the curl command and wget commands I am using:

wget -O file.jar 1.2.3.4:5678

curl 1.2.3.4:5678 -o file.jar

Things that are true and might be relevant:

The host (running the above kotlin code) is a windows machine, and the recipient is running linux.

The jar file was created on the host.

Sending the jar file over scp also works fine and results in an uncorupted file.

Regardless of whether curl or wget is used, the total bytes printed by the kotlin code is correct.

This behavior is 100% repeatable: its always exactly 5 bytes missing, only for jar files, regardless of my trying it on several recipient machines.

Obviously this isn't a huge problem, since just using wget winds up working fine, but I am curious why this problem would occur in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the wget documentation, it supports http(s) and ftp(s) protocols. What you are doing is neither. That fact that it works at all is likely because they handle non-compliant http servers in some particular way that works out for you.

If you want to do what you're doing, you could at least put a fake HTTP response in front of the contents of the file:

```
out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"
          .getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I guess it never occurred to me to think about wget and curl as other than just reading a stream of bytes, because that happened to be what I wanted from them. Thanks!